# Partial Vlookup not finding value on Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, textjoin

I was trying on Google Sheets a very simple VLookup with partial match (using wild card), and for some reason I can't seem to make that work. My formula is rather simple:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",$D:$E,2,0)
```

Where **D:E** is my lookup table and **A2** is the cell to be partially searched. I'm searching for the word "John J" while in my lookup table I have "John" with Id 1. So my VLOOKUP above should return 1.

[image]

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yRKlMEQmgOOPvtrk0_0s-Qw1zL7-x8a5zHStu5RRVgI/edit#gid=0) is the Google Spreadsheet with the issue. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: The wildcard characters don't exclude part of cell A2 from the search key. They simply allow for additional characters in the search key, and any value in the lookup range that meets that expanded criteria will be returned. So, for example, "John J190" in the lookup range would be a valid match. Is that behavior in your sheet intentional?

Comment: Ohh. I see your point, I had a complete misunderstanding of what was the "partial search".

The search is the other way around of what I was thinking about. So the word I'm looking for should be completely on the lookup table, but maybe the lookup table could have more characters. Like the example you gave.

It's clear! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do it like this:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A5, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D2:D)), D:E, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: However it doesn't work when you look for "oh", it gives a blank value, instead of returning John.

Comment: @DavidSalomon ofc it wont work, unless you have "oh" in D column (and value for it in E column)

Comment: I know, but I mentioned it, because by using ` "*"&A2&"*" ` it works

Comment: Right DavidSalomon, but @player0 answer actually is what I desired, I was not very clear on what I actually wanted to do. What I wanted is exactly what the proposal is doing:  by having a very detailed string to be searched like "John J" or " J John" or "Alisson John J" or even "Johnson" I wanted to make a search if a generic name like "John" would match that search and return its id.

Comment: @player0 I don't think your formula would need to go from A2:A5 correct? It should be A2 only I guess. And I also don't think you need the INDEX() part of the formula correct? But I got your idea anyway, it's a nice approach. Thanks

Comment: @JonatasGrandini yes, only if you processing an array